# Understanding the stem(s) of 'struere'

Tags: verbs, language-evolution, morphology, grammar-identification, conjugation

The present, perfect, and participle stems<sup>1</sup> of the verb *struere* are *stru-*, *strux-*, and *struct-*.
The *-s-* in the perfect stem and the *-t-* in the participle stem are nothing unusual, but they seem to follow a consonant that is absent from the present stem, perhaps *-c-*, *-g-*, or *-h-*.

The situation is similar to, for example, *trah-/trax-/tract-* and *dic-/dix-/dict-*.
A partial example with a *-g-* is *tang-/tetig-/tact-*, which could all naturally come from a single stem *tag-*.
**The thing I don't understand is why there is no consonant at the end of the present stem of *struere*.**

Was there ever a consonant that was later dropped — was it *struhere* or *strucere* or something similar?
If not, what explains the discrepancy between the present stem *stru-* and the two other stems?
Or is this just an irregularity I should accept without explanation?
I fail to see a story behind the paradigm *stru-/strux-/struct-*, although I can justify most Latin verb paradigms at least to myself.
Any explanation about the background of the stems of *struere* would be welcome.

---

<sup>1</sup>
I don't know the canonical names of these stems, but that's tangential.
I hope the terminology is clear enough.
I prefer short names for fluency.

Comment: I've mostly heard them called the "first, second, and third" stems, or the "present, perfect, and participle" stems

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The form *structum* seems to have "c" by analogy to stems that had labiovelar consonants in Proto-Indo-European, as Alex B. says.

> In *frūctus* (from *fruor*) the Indo-European present stem ended in a labio-velar *gʷ,* but various analogies no doubt account for *strūctus, flūxus,* old *flūctus, uīctum* (from *struo, fluo, uīuo*)
>   (*Vox Latina,* W. Sidney Allen, Second Edition, p. 69) (First published 1965, Second edition 1978)

There is also a relevant footnote on this page:

> 2. Old Latin [for *fīgo*] is in fact *fīuo,* with *u* from Indo-European *gʷ.* But note *nīxus* (and *nictare*) from *(co)nīveo,* where *u* is from Indo-European *gʷh.*

In Perkins (1875) I found the following examples of verbs that have a velar consonant only in non-present stems:

> - fluo, fluxi, fluctum/fluxum
> - struo, struxi, structum
> - vivo, vixi, victum

(p 36)

> - fruor, fructus/fruitus
> - nitor, nisus/nixus

(p 37)

"Latin Verbs in -uo, -uere", by Oswald Szemerényi, says

> Two [*of the verbs ending in -uo, -uere*] show in the perfect and the PPP a velar stem:
>
> > *fluo -ere fluxī fluctum* (later *fluxus*)
> >     
> > *struo -ere struxī structum.*
>
> No doubt ... the same type is seen in
>
> > *fruor fruī frūctus*

(p. 11)

Wiktionary (accessed 24 June 2017) gives the following etymologies:

- [fluo](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fluo#Latin): "From Proto-Italic *flowō" (cites De Vaan), "from Proto-Indo-European **bʰlewgʷ-,* from **bʰlew-*"
- [struo](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/struo#Latin): "From Proto-Italic *strowō" (cites De Vaan) "with spurious *c* in *struxī* and *structum*"
- [vivo](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vivo#Latin): "From Proto-Italic *gʷīwō [...] The *x* and *c* in *vīxī* and *vīctum* were introduced by analogy with other verbs." I left out what Wiktionary says about the Indo-European etymology because my understanding is that this is a somewhat troublesome root to analyze
- [fruor](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fruor#Latin): "From the Proto-Indo-European **bʰruHg-*" (De Vaan is listed in the "references" section, but there's no explicit citation and no Proto-Italic form given)
- [nitor](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nitor#Latin): "From Proto-Indo-European **kneygʷʰ-* (“to bend, to droop”). Cognate with *nicō, connīveō, nictō*"

As you might have noticed, Wiktionary, unlike Allen, doesn't write a macron on *structum,* and there is a note in the Wiktionary entry for *struo* saying:

> Please note that there is a disagreement over whether or not there is a macron on the third and fourth principal parts and the subsequent verb forms from these (*strūxī* for *struxī* and *strūctum* for *structum*).

However, there is no citation for this statement, so I don't know what the basis for the disagreement would be.

Bennett (1907) says

> Gellius [...] testifies (*Noctes Atticae,* 
>   ix. 6) to the quantity of the vowels of *āctus, lēctus, ūnctus,* and in 
>   xii. 3. 4 to that of ***strūctus*** (p. 52)

and

> the Romance languages [...] point to *cīnxī, distīnxī, exstīnxī, fīnxī, pīnxī, **strūxī,** tīnxī, ūnxī* (p. 53)

but perhaps there are some issues with this evidence, or opposing pieces of evidence. Bennet doesn't indicate any inscriptional evidence (e.g. use of the [apex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apex_(diacritic))) for vowel length in this word.

#### Works cited

- Allen, W. Sidney. *Vox Latina,* Second Edition (First published 1965, Second edition 1978)
- Bennet, Charles E. *[The Latin language; a historical outline of its sounds, inflections, and syntax](https://archive.org/stream/latinlanguagehis00benn#page/52/mode/2up)* (1907)
- Perkins, John. *[Latin and Greek Accidence](https://books.google.com/books?id=KwZyJh3QgDEC&pg=PA36&lpg=PA36&dq=fluo%20fluxum%20fluctum%20fruor%20fructus&source=bl&ots=ZXCASg4GJQ&sig=fMotdFecey-Rwu5FVMOYhRmFwyQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjjyZud5dfUAhUL5oMKHSpYCBsQ6AEILjAB#v=onepage&q=fructus&f=false)* (1875)
- Szemerényi, Oswald. "[Latin Verbs in -uo, -uere](https://books.google.com/books?id=1mVwAuuC8GoC&pg=PA12&lpg=PA12&dq=vowel%20length%20%22struxi%22&source=bl&ots=-LmXUZCyDT&sig=2uwMYrKtuV_XXFA-xrqOdclpYCA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjLwrn6odjUAhVExoMKHZhxDbkQ6AEINDAF#v=snippet&q=struo&f=false)", in *Italic and Romance Linguistic Studies in Honor of Ernst Pulgram* (1980). This seems pretty detailed! I can only see part of it through Google Books, but it looks worth a read.

#### Further reading

Some links to further literature that seems relevant that I found by Googling, but that I haven't processed yet:

- "[On some Slavic words in *-č*: *k* from laryngeal?](https://books.google.com/books?id=--ssbDUSJfIC&pg=PA344&lpg=PA344&dq=vowel%20length%20%22struxi%22&source=bl&ots=OnRD8wQlyO&sig=LXJvc7ZmMZalhjEHkOk5TfjlpD8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjLwrn6odjUAhVExoMKHZhxDbkQ6AEIMTAE#v=onepage&q=vowel%20length%20%22struxi%22&f=false)", by Jens Elmegård Rasmussen (1988)
- "[Lachmann's Law (Part 2)](https://digilib.phil.muni.cz/bitstream/handle/11222.digilib/127146/1_LinguisticaBrunensia_14-2013-1_2.pdf?sequence=1)", by Roman Sukač (2013)
- "[On Latin *strāgulum* and *strāges*: *-g-* and analogy](https://books.google.com/books?id=SoQIDgAAQBAJ&pg=PA234&lpg=PA234&dq=vowel%20length%20%22struxi%22&source=bl&ots=XVqslgIwak&sig=ufCsDbYWCXFelNLOLVQfkdFcGt4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjLwrn6odjUAhVExoMKHZhxDbkQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=vowel%20length%20%22struxi%22&f=false)", by Kanehiro Nishimura, in *Words and Dictionaries: A Festschrift for Professor Stanisław Stachowski on the Occassion of his 85<sup>th</sup> Birthday* (2015)

Comment: A side note. We know that **eu > ū**, so it's not quite clear why some (who?) speculate there was shortening in struxi or structum.

Comment: @AlexB.: I'm also confused by the statement in Wikipedia. But perhaps the thought is that, since it was an analogical form, it might have assimilated to the form of words like *ductus* with short "u" before "ct". Or maybe there is unconclusive evidence from other authors or from Romance reflexes

Comment: let's see if TKR or fdb adds anything.

Answer (score 8):

A good question.

- Assimilation (voice): * tagto > * takto. This is a common phenomenon,
  cf. scribo-scripsi, veho-vixi etc. (see e.g. Weiss, p. 188, I.1);
- With **dico**, there's nothing unusual: diksi, dikto;
- With **struo**: k was inserted there analogically. Verbs ending in a
  labiovelar (k<sup>w</sup>, g<sup>w</sup>) follow this pattern:

> 1. "the labial element of a labiovelar is deleted before a consonant"
>      (Weiss, p. 188)

coquo- coxi, unguo - unxi

> 2. "Labial and velar stops are devoiced and deaspirated before a voiceless obstruent" (Weiss, p. 188) - in other words, our voice assimilation again:

unguo - unxi

fivo (i.e. figo) - fixi

fluo - fluxi

coniveo - conixi

(Examples taken from Tronskii 1960, pp. 260-261).

Remember that **PIE *g<sup>w</sup> > Lat. u̯** (unless after a nasal).

**So, this rule applied - by analogy - to some verbs without a labiovelar**, e.g. vivo-vixi or struo-struxi.

cf. Weiss "[a]lterations caused by the differing outcomes of the voiced labiovelars in prevocalic and preconsonantal position would lead to an alternation -u̯-V ~ -kT-" (p. 441)

or Meiser 1998:

[image]