# Are there other verbs in -uō?

Tags: verbs, conjugation, vowel-quantity

Someone asked me recently about the conjugation of the obscene verb *futuō, futuere, futuī, futūtus*—and in particular about the quantity of the *ū* in the participle.

I intended to look at some other *-uō* verbs to compare them, but realized I couldn't think of any others off the top of my head. The only one that came to mind was *renuō*, which is intransitive and doesn't have a passive participle. (L&S don't list a future participle either, which I'm taking to mean that form is unattested.)

Are there other verbs in *-uō*? And if so, do they have participles in *-ūtus*? (Intransitive verbs with participles in *-ūturus* are also welcome!)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is *abluō, abluere, abluī, ablūtus*.

And *acuō, acuere, acuī, acūtus*.

And *arguō, arguere, arguī, argūtus*.

And *compluō, compluere, compluī, complūtus*.

And *exuō, exuere, exuī, exūtus*.

And *futuō, futuere, futuī, futūtus*.

And *imbuō, imbuere, imbuī, imbūtus*.

And *minuō, minuere, minuī, minūtus*.

And *rŭo, ruere, rŭi, rŭtus*.

And *spŭo, spuere, spui, spūtus*.

And *statuō, statuere, statuī, statūtus*.

And *suō, suere, suī, sūtus*.

And *tribuō, tribuere, tribuī, tribūtus*.

Note that some/many future participles of the above verbs go *-uitūrus* rather than *-uturus*.

If you will accept *volvo, voluere, volvi, volutus*, considering that u/v was one letter in Latin script (though not sound), perhaps *vŏlūtus* will do? At least the participle has a real, vocalic *u*.

The participle *locūtus/loquūtus* could also be interesting, if you will accept  a verb with first person singular present *-quo-.* (*loquor*).

The same applies to *sĕcūtus* from *sequor*.

Those are all participles on -utus that I could find. So the *only* participle with a short -ŭ- is *rŭo*. I wonder why!

Comment: Not only are there a good number of ppps in -utus in Classical Latin, this ending becomes generalised for the ppp of fourth conj. verbs in Romance (venu, venuto etc.)

Comment: Don't all _-struō/-strūctus_ verbs belong to the answer as an additional category? Not sure at all: quantity is not my area of expertise

Comment: @Rafael: Well, I only included verbs with a p. p. p. on -utus. Feel free to add all other verbs on -uo to my answer in a secondary list (I'm too tired!).

Answer (score 5):

Szemerényi (1980) says that the following "descriptive rule" summarizes the conjugation pattern for verbs ending in *-uo*:

> verbs in *-uo* in general form their perfect in *-uī,* their PPP in *-ūtus* (even *tuor/tūtus* would conform to this rule!); a list would have to specify four exceptions: *ruo* has *rūtus,* but in the compounds  *-rŭtus*; two verbs which have a velar in the perfect (*fluxī, struxī*) show it in the PPP, too, as does *frūctus* from *fruor.*

(pp. 11-12)

I was a bit confused by the rule saying that the length of the vowel in *-rutus* depends on whether the word is a compound. The explanation actually seems to be that there are two different verbs that have *ruo* as the first principal part. Szemerényi refers to them as ¹*ruo* and ²*ruo.* For more details, see [my answer to the related question "Why is there a short ŭ in rŭtus?"](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/6456/9)

### Lists of verbs

On p. 11, before giving the rule that I quoted earlier in this answer,  Szemerényi lists and categorizes the verbs:

> 2.1. [...]
>   
> (a) A small group has no forms for the PPP and in some cases not even for the perfect. Here belong:
>
> ```
> battuo      -ere     -uī     --
> ¹cluo       -ere     --      --
> ²cluo       -ere     --      --
> (con)gruo   -ere     -uī     --
> gruo        -ere     --      --   
> pluit       -ere    -uit     --  
> sternuo     -ere    -uit     --
> ```
>
> (b) The great majority – fifteen verbs – show *-uī* and *-ūtum* in these forms. They are: *acuo, arguo, futuo, imbuo, induo, (ē)luo, metuo, minuo, nuo, polluo,* ²*ruo, spuo, statuo, suo, tribuo.* We should perhaps add here *dēlibūtus,* and certainly also ²*luo* as shown by *solūtum* (see fn. 2).
>
> (c) Two verbs deviate from this main type in that they show *-ŭtum.* One of them is attested in Classical times: ¹*ruo-rutum.* For the other, ¹*cluo,* the form *clutus* is indirectly attested by *inclutus* 'famous'.
>
> (d) Two other verbs show in the perfect and the PPP a velar stem:
>
> ```
> fluo       -ere     fluxī      fluctum (later fluxus)
> struo      -ere     struxī     structum.
> ```
>
> No doubt (see also 3.1 (8) further down) the same type is seen in
>
> ```
> fruor      fruī     frūctus;
> ```
>
> the form *frūctus* was the norm in Classical times, *fruitus* is a later innovation, perhaps preceded by  *fruitūrus* (Cicero).
>
> The same formation as in *fruitus* is seen in *tuitus,* which again seems later than *tūtus.*

Although Szemerényi doesn't seem to mention it, the supine of ¹*ruo* likewise seems to have had the variant form *ruitum* at some point.

There is more discussion of the forms and their probable development in the paper. Unfortunately, I can't really summarize it (partly because it is very detailed, and partly because I haven't been able to read it through yet because I've only accessed it through Google Books).

But at the end, there is a categorization of the verbs according to etymology and a passage that seems to explain the long vowel in the ending *-ūtus* for many of the verbs:

> 3.2. On the strength of our findings in 3.1, we can group the twenty-nine verbs in *-uo* according to the original formations as follows:
>
> (a) thematic root-formations (*-ewō,* one instance *-owō*): ²*cluo,* ¹*luo, pluit,* ¹*ruo, struo*;
>   
> (b) thematized nasal-infix formation: *sternuo*;
>   
> (c) primary *-yo*: *induo (*end-au-yō); fluo (*bhleug-yō); fruor (*bhrūg-yō-r);* ¹*gruo (*grū-yō,* or *gruwō?);* ²*gruo (*grū-yō,* or *gru-it?);* ²*luo (*lū̆-yō); polluo (**³*lŭ-yō,* or **lowō?);* ²*ruo (*rū-yō); spuo (*spyū-yō); suo (*syū-yō);*
>   
> (d) denominative *-yo*: *acuo, arguo, futuo, metuo, minuo, statuo, tribuo* (all *-ŭyō* or *-ūyō?);*
>   
> (e) pairs of basic verb and intensive (cf. *σπένδω: spondeo; *tendo, tondeo*): 
>   
> *nuo : nueo (*newō : *noweyō)*
>   
> *tuor : tueor (*tewōr : *toweyōr)*
>   
> *?cluo : clueo (*klewō : *kloweyō?* but rather late innovation ¹*cluo* beside old *clueo*);
>   
> (f): of obscure structure: *battuo, dēlibūtus, imbuo.*
>
> 4. The PPP has, as we have seen (2.1), *-ūtus* in the denominatives. This is what we should expect in any case, seeing that before the suffix *-to* the stem-final vowel is lengthened even in purely adjectival forms; c.f. *aurītus, crīnītus, turrītus,* on the one hand, *argūtus, cinctūtus, cornūtus, versūtus, verūtus,* on the other, and, outside Italy, e.g., Greek *δακρῡτός* 'wept over, tearful'.

(p. 28)

### Works cited

Szemerényi, Oswald. 1980. "[Latin Verbs in uo, uere](https://books.google.com/books?id=1mVwAuuC8GoC&pg=PA12&lpg=PA12&d#v=onepage&q&f=false)". *Italic and Romance Linguistic Studies in Honor of Ernst Pulgram,* edited by Herbert J. Izzo.

De Vaan, Michiel. 2008. *Etymological Dictionary of Latin and the Other Italic Languages.*

Comment: Related: [Understanding the stem(s) of 'struere'](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4654/understanding-the-stems-of-struere)