# Are there verbs in -o-?

Tags: verbs, conjugation, vowel

Verbs conjugated in -a- (amō, amāre, amāvī, amātus), in -e- (habeō, habēre, habuī, habitus), and in -i- (audio, audīre, audīvī, auditus) are common and well-known. Verbs in -u- (acuō, acuere, acuī, acūtus) are less common and grouped in with the third (consonant) conjugation, but [they definitely exist](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/6435/406).

But are there any verbs in -o-? They're not common but certainly not unheard of in Greek (e.g. *δηλόω dēlóō* "show") and their complete absence seems odd in Latin. If there really aren't any, what happened to them?

Comment: Research lead: [-oo verbs](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/resolveform?type=end&lookup=oo&lang=la). But as a Spanish speaker I can't help looking at the infinitives and say -u- verbs are still -ere verbs

Comment: @Rafael That search is precisely how I produced my answer. (This also addresses Draconis's question below: you can search for words ending with a specific string on Perseus. In fact, it would be useful to have questions about dictionary search tools.)

Comment: @Rafael Oh, they definitely conjugate just like consonant-stems, but the stems themselves seem to end in -u. (So you get -u-ō, -u-ere, -u-vī > -u-ī, -u-itus > -ūtus or something like that, like how the first conjugation has -a-ō > -ō, -a-ere > āre, -a-vī > -āvī, -a-itus > -ātus.)

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Ah, thank you! That's very useful, and I should ask a proper question about these tools when I have a chance. Is it able to search for inflected forms? I tried searching for -oere (which I expected to turn up *boere* and maybe some actual o-stems) and got nothing.

Comment: @Draconis Perseus won't find inflected forms, but perhaps some other tool out there will. And then there's also the possibility of searching a corpus instead of a dictionary. Example: [words ending in *-oo*](http://latin.packhum.org/search?q=oo%23).

Answer (score 5):

Lewis and Short give only three Latin words ending in *-oo*, all of them verbs:

- [*boare/boere*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dboo), "to cry"
- [*reboare*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dreboo), "to echo" (the previous one with *re-*)
- [*inchoare*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dinchoo), an alternative spelling of *incohare*

Apart from *boere*, these are all first conjugation verbs and their present stem ends in *a*.
They are not what you asked for, but they seem to be the closest thing there is in Latin.
The form *boare* also appears as *bovare*, but *boere* only without the *-v-*.
Therefore the closest thing to *o*-stem verbs in Latin is *boere*, but there may be too few attestations to draw strong conclusions.

Comment: These are interesting, but the stems themselves seem to be *bova-*, *rebova-*, and *incoha-*. (L&S mention the *v* and *h*, and the *a* shows in the conjugation. The *-a-* in *bova-* can also be seen in the Greek cognate, which is an a-contract.)

Comment: @Draconis True. The point was that these are the closest we have to o-stem verbs in Latin. I'll expand.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how are you searching L&S for these? I'm used to accessing the text through Perseus, which is great for looking up individual words but not good for finding *all* the words matching a criterion.

Comment: @Draconis I didn't see Joonas's answer. But I was thinking the same: the roots are more explicitly -are. Yet they are the closest one can think of... Unless there was 1) a verb in -oo, -ois, -oere, or 2) something oddly irregular. 1) seems ruled out by L&S, 2) seems very unlikely to me

Comment: Apart from that…it seems likely that -o-ō would contract to -ō in Latin, like how ama-ō > amō, and dēlóō > dēlô in Greek. Is there any way to search for inflected forms like -oere?

Comment: @Draconis when searching in Perseus, you can choose to look for exact words, or words beginning/ending with/containing a pattern

Comment: @Draconis If *-oo>-o*, then why doesn't *-eo>-o* and *-io>-o* and *-uo>-o*? (To be honest, I don't know why the first conjugation contracts but the others don't. Understanding that might help.)

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Good question! Probably deserves to be asked separately. I can't think of any Latin words that actually have *ao* or *oo* in them (except the ones listed above), but plenty with *eo* and *io*, and a few with *uo*.

Comment: @Draconis Studying contractions certainly merits asking separate questions. It would be great to be able to predict contractions rather than only justifying sound changes by them. (There are words like *Danaos* and *coortus*, but I don't find these examples for *-ao-* and *-oo-* fully satisfying.)